# Eigenvalues of Superpositions

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, quantum-spin, superposition, eigenvalue

First, consider the following superposition of two orthonormal spin states, $|1\rangle$ and $|0\rangle$:

$$|\Psi\rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(|1\rangle + |0\rangle)$$

$|\Psi\rangle$ would be an eigenstate of both of the following operators:

\begin{align}
O_{1} &= (|1\rangle + |0\rangle)(\langle 0| + \langle 1|) \\
O_{2} &= |1\rangle \langle 1| + |0\rangle \langle 0|
\end{align}

Now, $O_{2} |\Psi\rangle = 1 \cdot |\Psi \rangle$, which I think is intuitive, because $O_{2}$ seems to correspond to the question, "Are you in some linear combination of $|1\rangle$ and $|0\rangle$, or something like that. And I take it that the eigenvalue '1' in this case can be interpreted as "Yes." (Correct me if I'm wrong.)

But $O_{1}|\Psi\rangle = 2| \Psi \rangle $, and I don't understand the physical meaning of the eigenvalue '2' here. I guess that $O_{1}$ can be thought of as corresponding to the question "Are you in a (non-trivial) superposition of $|1\rangle$ and $|0\rangle$?", and I'm not sure what having an eigenvalue of 2 with respect to $O_{1}$signifies in physical terms.

I'm sorry to ask the 'physical meanings' of mathematical results, which some people might find purely non-sensical. But it's just to have an intuitive grasp of the formalism, and I would appreciate any insights.

Comment: $O_2$ is the identity matrix, and $O_1$ would be an idempotent projection operator to your state, *if only* you normalized it by 1/2.  What "physical" meaning are you seeking?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated by Cosmas Zachos in the comment section, $\hat{O}_2$ is nothing else than the identity matrix within the space generated by $|0\rangle$ and $|1\rangle$, so that the relation $\hat{O}_2|\Psi\rangle = |\Psi\rangle$ is trivial.

As for $\hat{O}_1$, note that $\frac{1}{2}\hat{O}_1 = |\Psi\rangle\langle\Psi|$ is the orthogonal projector onto the state $|\Psi\rangle$. In consequence, $\hat{O}_1$ captures the "overlap" between a given state and $|\Psi\rangle$. The 2-factor comes merely from the fact that the state $|0\rangle + |1\rangle$ is not normalized.